# creating xib file

Tags: iphone, interface-builder

how to create xib files like this?
below is the screen shot what am looking for?

note:- i want to create like sub file ( en)

[image]

Comment: Good one I was also searching for this. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Xcode 3.2.5 that I'm using, you right-click on the XIB, select Get Info, then there's a 'Make File Localizable' button, which will create the structure you're looking for and then allow you to add more languages (you have to translate the files yourself though ;-)

I have written a tutorial with more info on I18N if you're interested, [you'll find it here](http://blog.federicomestrone.com/2010/05/18/internationalise-your-iphone-apps-with-xcode/)...

Comment: Hi, Fedmest I have one query when i create a localization xib it creates a new xib but both Main.xib and en.xib both are opening. I want only en.xib to open.

Comment: there shouldn't be any en.xib - there is one Main.xib in the en.lproj folder... and there will be another Main.xib for every new localized folder you add to the list